# When should we use android.arch.lifecycle:compiler (or android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8)?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Currently, we are using `LiveData`, `ViewModel` and `Room` in our project.

We are using Java 8.

We use the following in `build.gradle`

```
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

// Room (use 1.1.0-beta1 for latest beta)
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

I was wondering, when do we need to use

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

(Or `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"` since we are using Java 8?!)

Currently, our code works fine, without using `lifecycle:compiler` or `lifecycle:common-java8`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> when do we need to use `annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"`

AFAIK, that's only needed if you have lifecycle-related annotations in your code, specifically `@OnLifecycleEvent`.

> Or implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1" since we are using Java 8?

Same thing. The docs state "If your app uses Java 8, we recommend using this library instead of `android.arch.lifecycle:compiler`."

Comment: Although it's not necessary - methods annotated with OnLifecycleEvent will be called using reflection

Answer (score 54):

Lifecycle annotation processor dependency declaration for Java 8 should be as following:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

Instead of:

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 19):

## Your options

As far as I can see you have 3 options:

### `LifecycleObserver`

It's a marker interface, it doesn't have any methods. Your class will implement it and then you define a bunch of `@OnLifecycleEvent` methods as you need.

Lifecycle runtime will do one of 2 things:

- Use reflection to look up the annotated methods,
- or use generated adapters if you enabled the `lifecycle-compiler` annotation processor.

This interface is part of the `lifecycle-common` library.

### `LifecycleEventObserver`

It provides a single method

```
void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source, @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event);
```

which will get called *instead of* any annotated methods.

This interface is part of the `lifecycle-common` library.

### `DefaultLifecycleObserver`

It provides an interface with several empty methods:

```
default void onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}
default void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}
default void onResume(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}
default void onPause(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}
default void onStop(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}
default void onDestroy(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {}
```

Your class will implement this interface and you can pick which methods to implement.

This interface is part of the `lifecycle-common-java8` library. Interfaces with some implemented methods (default methods) are supported since Java 8. If your project has [enabled Java 8 language features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) you can use it.

## What to make of it

`LifecycleEventObserver` and `DefaultLifecycleObserver` add methods to your class, this may not be what you want. It's definitely not what I like.

I'd expect that you create a method with semantically accurate name and tell the Lifecycle framework only *when* it should call it. Like so:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
public void startListening();
```

It doesn't pollute your class with extra methods. And you can use the annotation processor to make it faster at run-time. (The generated adapter is still looked up using reflection.)

I find this statement from [Lifecycle release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) inaccurate:

> ```
> annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
> // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
> implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
> ```

The compiler generates an adapter so you don't have to alter your class' interface. It works totally different from `DefaultLifecycleObserver`.

Answer (score 5):

android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1 is used when you write custom class implementing LifecycleObserver

```
public class MyObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void connectListener() {
        ...
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    public void disconnectListener() {
        ...
    }
}
```

extracted from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html

Comment: Plus one for the link