# Unable to build android app in github actions, No matching configuration of project services was found

Tags: java, android, docker, gradle, github-actions

I am trying to build the app in github actions but I am facing an error which doesn't happen to me on my device when I run `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`

```
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :services.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :services was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The project is a multimodule app

Here is the services gradle file

```
import dependencies.Apollo
import dependencies.Dependencies
import dependencies.RoomDependencies
import dependencies.Versions

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("com.apollographql.apollo3")
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
apollo {
    useVersion2Compat()
    generateKotlinModels.set(true)
    srcDir("src/main/graphql")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion Versions.compilesdk
    buildToolsVersion Versions.buildTools
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
              }
        debug {

        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
dependencies {
    kapt("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:3.2.1")
    implementation(Apollo.APOLLO_CACHE)
    implementation(Apollo.APOLLO_SQL)
    implementation project( ":linguisticdomain")
    // retrofit
    implementation(Dependencies.retrofit)
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0")

    // room
    implementation(RoomDependencies.room_ktx)
    implementation(RoomDependencies.room_runtime)
    kapt(RoomDependencies.room_compiler)
    implementation(RoomDependencies.ROOM_TEST)
}
```

Here is the app gradle file

```
import dependencies.*
import dependencies.dependencies.SupportDependencies
import dependencies.dependencies.TestDependencies

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion Versions.compilesdk
    buildToolsVersion Versions.buildTools


    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true

    }


    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId Application.id
        minSdkVersion Versions.minsdk
        targetSdkVersion Versions.targetsdk
        versionCode Application.version_code
        versionName "1.0.2"

        testInstrumentationRunner AndroidTestDependencies.instrumentation_runner

        // ...
        // Set the properties within `local.properties` into a `Properties` class so that values
        // within `local.properties` (e.g. Maps API key) are accessible in this file.
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        if (rootProject.file("local.properties").exists()) {
            properties.load(rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())
        }

        // Inject the Maps API key into the manifest
        manifestPlaceholders = [mapsApiKey: properties.getProperty("MAPS_API_KEY", "")]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "true"]
        }
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled: "true"]
        }
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion Versions.kotlin
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion Compose.version
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project( ":linguisticdomain")
    implementation project( ":services")

    // Kotlin
    implementation Dependencies.kotlin_standard_library
    implementation Dependencies.ktx
    //implementation Dependencies.kotlin_extensions

    //support
    implementation SupportDependencies.appcompat
    implementation SupportDependencies.constraintlayout
    implementation SupportDependencies.material_design
    implementation SupportDependencies.legacy_support

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'




    //test
    testImplementation TestDependencies.junit4
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //navigation
    implementation Dependencies.navigation_fragment
    implementation Dependencies.navigation_ui

    //ktx
    implementation Dependencies.fragment_ktx
    //apollo
    implementation("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:3.2.1")
    implementation(Apollo.APOLLO_CACHE)
    implementation(Apollo.APOLLO_SQL)

    compileOnly "org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1"

    //Build interactive settings screens without needing to interact with device storage or manage the UI.
    implementation Dependencies.android_preferences

    testCompileOnly "org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1"

    //debugging
    implementation Dependencies.timber
    //view_pager2
    implementation Dependencies.view_pager2
    // retrofit
    implementation Dependencies.retrofit
    implementation Dependencies.converter_moshi

    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'

    implementation Dependencies.kotlin_coroutines_android
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'


    implementation Compose.compose_ui
    implementation Compose.compose_tooling
    implementation Compose.compose_foundation
    implementation Compose.compose_material
    implementation Compose.compose_material_icons
    implementation Compose.compose_material_icons_ext
    implementation Compose.compose_activity
    implementation Compose.compose_viewModel
    implementation Compose.compose_livedata
    implementation Compose.constraint_layout
    implementation Compose.compose_run_time
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'

    implementation 'com.sagar:coroutinespermission:2.0.3'



    // UI Tests
    //   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.ui:ui-test:1.0.0-alpha05'
    androidTestImplementation TestDependencies.arch_core_testing

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42"


    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'
    //this gets warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602410/when-should-we-use-android-arch-lifecyclecompiler-or-android-arch-lifecycleco
//    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0"
    implementation Dependencies.work_manager
    implementation Dependencies.lottie_compose
    implementation Dependencies.lottie
    implementation Accompanist.insets
    implementation Accompanist.navigation_animation
    implementation Accompanist.coil

    implementation GoogleMaps.maps
    implementation GoogleMaps.mapsKtx
    implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha"
    implementation "io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.4.0"

    //firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-iid")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2'

    //pusher beams
    implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android:1.6.2'

    // Activity Compose
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1"

    // CameraX
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha31"

    // qrcode
    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0') { transitive = false }
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    implementation 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.3'

}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
    generateStubs = true

}
```

The github action code

```
name: Distribute to app distribution

on:
  pull_request:


jobs:
  distribute:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: alvrme/alpine-android:android-33-jdk11
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Cache Gradle
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches/
          key: cache-clean-gradle-${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.jdk }}

      - name: Cache Gradle Wrapper
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/wrapper/
          key: cache-clean-wrapper-${{ matrix.os }}-${{ matrix.jdk }}

      - name: Grant Permission to Execute
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Distribute app with  App Distribution 
        run: |
          extras fastlane
          fastlane android increment_release_name
          fastlane android distribute
```

And that's the complete [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/DavidIbrahim/98a13e2a0fde190e83c0ebd4e3f93c00)

Comment: `using docker` - did you copy/mount all the files needed? I'd need to see the whole GH Action.

Comment: @lukee the strange thing is that if I removed the services module and merged the code in the app module, it works without a problem. I added the GitHub action file to the question.

Comment: any updates? still facing the same issue

Comment: @tamtom No, still stuck

Comment: @DavidIbrahim we were able to solve the issue, my issue was the directory name on GitHub was all small latter, while the module name has some capital characters, it seems the environment of GitHub action is case sensitive, so changing the directory and the module name to lower case worked